# Djagno and React useContext function with axios don't work

Tags: reactjs, django

I am doing and app with django and react and I want to add authentication. I do it with jwt. Here is the code.

AuthContext.js

```
export const AuthProvide = ({children}) => {

    const [authToken, setAuthToken] = useState(null)
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null)


    function loginUser(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(e)
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/', {
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            username: e.target.name.value,
            password: e.target.password.value
        })
    }

    let contextData = {
        user: user,
        token: authToken,
        loginUser: loginUser,
    }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={contextData}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )

}
```

Login.js

```
import AuthContext from "../context/AuthContext";

const Login = () => {

    const {loginUser} = useContext(AuthContext)

    return (    
        <>
            <Header />
            <form onSubmit={loginUser}>
                <input  type='text' name='username' />
                <input  type='password' name='password' />
                <button onClick={loginUser}>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </>
    )
}
```

App.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
          <AuthProvide> 
            <Routes>
              <Route element={<PrivateRoute/>}>
                <Route path='/' element={<Home/>} />
              </Route>
              <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>} />
            </Routes>
          </AuthProvide>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

But when I run the form  I get `settle.js:19 Uncaught (in promise) zt {message: 'Request failed with status code 401', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}`

and AuthContext.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value') in  console. In django I did it from django jwt [docs](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)

Comment: What response do you see in Network tab of your browser?

Comment: It should be 401, as stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

you are not using the right way to send the data inside your `loginUser` Function. the `e.target.username.value` will not give you value of `username` field input (by the way you have used `e.target.name.value`, which will anyway not give the value)

1. you have to define the `loginUser` function inside your Login.js component.
2. you have to save the `username` and `password` fields' value in a state by using `useState` hook of react.
3. Later that, you can share the response you get from the API via authcontext to whichever component within your authcontext if you save it in your shared state

Answer (score 0):

In the `AuthContext.js`,

```js
export const AuthProvide = ({children}) => {

    const [authToken, setAuthToken] = useState(null)
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        username: null,
        password: null
    })

    function loginUser(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        // Header Config
        const config = {
            headers: {
              "Content-type": "application/json",
              Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`,
            },
          };
            
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/', // FIXME: You probably want to relook at how to call a POST method or how to name your APIs properly.
            user,
            config
        )
    }

    let contextData = {
        user: user,
        setUser: setUser,
        token: authToken,
        loginUser: loginUser,
    }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={contextData}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )

}
```

1. `useState()` to capture the user input for username and password.

In the `Login.js`,

```js
import AuthContext from "../context/AuthContext";

const Login = () => {
  const { user, setUser, loginUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <form onSubmit={loginUser}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="username"
          value={user.username}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setUser((prevState) => {
              return {
                ...prevState,
                username: e.target.value,
              };
            })
          }
        />
        <input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          value={user.password}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setUser((prevState) => {
              return {
                ...prevState,
                password: e.target.value,
              };
            })
          }
        />
        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

1. Export the Login component as default.
2. Use states provided by context to capture and update the respective values.